# Scala recursive generics: Parent[Child] and Child[Parent]

Tags: generics, scala, types

***Update**: Clarified and expanded, since the original question was simplified too far*

I need a pair of traits, each of which refers to the other such that parent and child classes must relate to each other.

```
trait Parent [C <: Child] {
  def foo(c: C)
}

trait Child [P <: Parent] {
  def parent: P = ...
  def bar = parent.foo(this)
}
```

Such that implementing classes must come in pairs:

```
class ActualParent extends Parent [ActualChild] {
  def foo(c: ActualChild) = ...
}

class ActualChild extends Child [ActualParent] {
}
```

Unfortunately, the compiler doesn't like these traits because the generic types aren't complete. Instead of `C <: Child` it needs to say `C <: Child[`*something*`]`. Leaving them unspecified doesn't work either:

```
trait Parent [C <: Child[_]] {
  def foo(c: C)
}

trait Child [P <: Parent[_]] {
  def parent: P = ...
  def bar = parent.foo(this)
}
```

It now complains on the `parent.foo(this)` line, because it doesn't know that `this` is of the correct type. The type of `parent` needs to be `Parent[this.type]` for the call to `foo` to have the right types.

I'm thinking there must be a way of referring to an object's own type? Or to a type that's required to be itself?

---

***Update***: Further to @Daniel's answer, I tried using an abstract type member within the child to state the generic types of the parent type like this:

```
trait Parent [C <: Child] {
  def foo(c: C)
}

trait Child {
  type P <: Parent[this.type]

  def parent: P = ...
  def bar = parent.foo(this)
}
```

This isn't working when I try to implement it:

```
class ActualParent extends Parent [ActualChild] {
  def foo(c: ActualChild) = ...
}

class ActualChild extends Child {
  type P = ActualParent
}
```

Gives the following error:

```
overriding type Parent in trait Child with bounds >: Nothing <: Parent[ActualChild.this.type]
type Parent has incompatible type
```

What does that mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the approach given in http://programming-scala.labs.oreilly.com/ch13.html:

```
abstract class ParentChildPair {
  type C <: Child
  type P <: Parent

  trait Child {self: C =>
    def parent: P
  }

  trait Parent {self: P =>
    def child: C
  }
}

class ActualParentChildPair1 {
  type C = Child1
  type P = Parent1

  class Child1 extends Child {...}

  class Parent1 extends Parent {...}
}
```

Comment: That looks correct. Now how would you expand that to include chains of parent -> child -> child?

Comment: This approach is successful, but I don't quite feel satisfied with it. I'm not sure I can adequately explain why.

Answer (score 3):

It can be done with abstract type members.

```
class Parent {
  type C <: Child
  def child: C = null.asInstanceOf[C]
}

class Child {
  type P <: Parent
  def parent: P = null.asInstanceOf[P]
}
```

Comment: That gets me past the compiler warning, but doesn't enforce the condition that parent and child class must each relate to the other.

Comment: See my answer based on abstract type members.

Answer (score 3):

Further to @Daniel's answer, I can use an abstract type member within the child to state the generic types of the parent type like this:

```
trait Parent [C <: Child] {
  def foo(c: C)
}

trait Child {
  type P <: Parent[this.type]

  def parent: P = ...
  def bar = parent.foo(this)
}
```

`this.type` isn't usable directly in generics, but in a parameter it seems to be fine. This approach is a lot less long-winded than the surrounding abstract class, and allows more flexible uses such as children that are also parents.

Answer (score 1):

You can write `C <: Child[_]`.

Comment: I guess that will work, but I think the OP is after a shortcut for Parent[C < Child[Parent[C < Child[Parent[C < Child] ... etc for infinity. :)

Comment: As Synesso said, Child[_] won't enforce that parents and children be matched to each other.

Comment: Why do you want to use generics? Why not using parameters: class Parent(c: Child); class Child(p: Parent)

Comment: @Synesso: how could you even instantiate such a hypothetical type?

Comment: @Antoras: I want to make sure the parent and child types are tied together, not actual instances. The question is a simplification, perhaps too far: they are actually traits that should be applied to implementing classes.

Comment: @pelotom - with great patience.

Answer (score 1):

Even though it wasn't successful, I'll record this avenue as an answer.

Using abstract type members, state bounds for the types referring back to `this.type`:

```
trait Parent {
  type C <: Child { type P <: this.type }
  def foo(c: C)
}

trait Child {
  type P <: Parent { type C <: this.type }
  def parent: P
  def bar = parent.foo(this)
}

class ActualParent extends Parent {
  type C = ActualChild
  def foo(c: ActualChild) = println("Hello")
}

class ActualChild extends Child {
  type P = ActualParent
  def parent = new ActualParent
}
```

The problem here is that the compiler doesn't connect `this` with the child type of the parent, so calling `parent.foo(this)` results in:

```
type mismatch
found : Child.this.type (with underlying type Child)
required: _3.C where val _3: Child.this.P
```